Consistent error booting into Kali Live in a Lenovo Yoga Aura Edition computer
I have had this issue for a while, and I thought the new Linux kernel release would fix it, but it didn’t.
I can’t figure out what the error is, I suspect something related to BIOS comparibility, but I cant boot Kali or any other Linux OS for that matter on this computer. Here are the error messages thrown when booting. (Compute: 83HM0001US)


This is a BIOS issue from the looks of it. Some people have apparently gotten an early version of the V62 BIOS that seems to work for the most part.
Personally, I've tried all the way up to Kernel version 6.12.6, still with no luck. Like the others said, 6.12 should have brought support for Lunar Lake, so this is likely a BIOS issue.
You can follow these threads to keep up to date on the matter, to see if/when Lenovo releases the updated BIOS.
https://www.reddit.com/r/Lenovo/comments/1gvjj9m/yoga_slim_7i_aura_edition_and_linux/
https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Yoga-Series-Laptops/Yoga-Slim-7-15ILL9-Beta-Bios-V62/m-p/5352094?page=1#6504044

The chief complaint seems to be No supported filesystem images found at /live. Unfortunately the screenshot provides no direct clues as to why that might be the case. If you're using an USB-based live media, the XHCI error messages suggest the kernel might be prevented from accessing it by the firmware... but this is just my guesswork.
Anyway, as a result, the boot cannot proceed beyond the initramfs stage, and crashes as PID #1 dies without a valid root filesystem image. No surprises there.
Here's what I can tell about the errors at the top of your screenshot:
intel-lpss 0000:00.19.1: probe with driver intel-lpss failed with error -2147483648

This is Intel Low Power SubSystem, which covers things like I2C and SPI buses and UARTs (serial ports and similar). It looks like the kernel module autoloading has detected this subsystem exists (by PCI(e) devices' vendor/product codes, most likely), but the driver failed to actually access the subsystem.
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: can't setup: -12
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: init 0000:00:14.0 fail, -12
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: probe with driver xhci_hcd failed with error -12

For some reason, the XHCI USB 3.x controller in your laptop cannot be initialized. That means anything connected via USB will probably not be working.
intel_ish_ipc 0000:00:12.0: ISH loader: request firmware intel/ish/ish_lnlm.bin failed:-2

The intel_ish_ipc is the driver for Intel's Integrated Sensor Hub, which is trying to find a firmware file /lib/firmware/intel/ish/ish_lnlm.bin and failing. That should not be essential for booting... but it tells me your system uses Intel's Lunar Lake mobile chipset (lnlm in the firmware file name).
Lunar Lake is a very new chipset: apparently you'll need the very latest kernel (6.12 series) for full support. 6.11 just barely passes the absolute minimum requirement.
Also, it seems (some?) 9th generation Lenovo Yoga laptops require extra I2C trickery to enable sound. You might have picked a challenging laptop model to run Linux on.

Thank you for your thorough answer! Also above those errors, there were some “ACPI BIOS” errors, if that tells you anything additional.

It is hard to guess their meaning without seeing the actual messages in full. But it does suggest there might be BIOS compatibility issues that the kernel may have to deal with in some specific way that needs to be discovered and then programmed in to the kernel.

Booting issues with Kali Live on a Lenovo Yoga Aura Edition may be caused by BIOS settings or hardware compatibility. Try these steps:
Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.
Enable Legacy Boot or CSM Mode if available.
Update BIOS Firmware to the latest version.
Use a Different USB Port or recreate the bootable USB using a reliable tool like Balena Etcher.
These steps usually resolve common boot errors.


Make bootable USB with Ventoy https://www.ventoy.net/en/download.html
Place on it different ISO images
Try to boot every one of it in different mode

